# Trying to get the parent of the closest class

Tags: jquery

I have some divs like:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="gChild">
     <button></button> 
    </div>
    <div class="gChild">
     <button></button> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <div class="gChild">
     <button></button> 
    </div>
    <div class="gChild">
     <button></button> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="NextSet">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="gChild">
     <button></button> 
    </div>
    <div class="gChild">
     <button></button> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I want to get the index of the 'child' from a button clicked. 
This works in the first set '#parent'

```
$(this).parents('.child').index();
```

But not in the second set '#NextSet' because all the .child elements from #parent are also added in parents(). 
I tried:

```
$(this).closest('.child').parent().index();
```

But that's not right...

Comment: so you want the index within all div.child elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`closest()` finds the first parent matching the selector, so it's just :

```
$(this).closest('.child').index()
```

`parents()` will find all parents matching the selector.

and to get the index within all `.child` elements, pass a collection :

```
$(this).closest('.child').index('.child');
```

Comment: your first answer actually looks like what he wants.. don't know who downvoted you

Comment: @wirey - I sure thought so?? Got downvotes immediately, so I was afraid I misunderstood, but I'm pretty sure the OP just added a `parent()` too much !

Comment: That gives me a similar result for the first item in #nextSet [1]... I think in this example because that is saying the closest .child is at [1] but it should give me [0]

Comment: @JamesFerreira - It does seem to work just as expected for me -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bQ47n/1/), are you sure your markup is valid etc.

Comment: Yes I see that so I'm must have a different problem. This is running through Google Caja and I can't see the source is gibberish b/c it's running from Google Apps Script HTML Service. On the second set I get 0, 2, 4. Why it's going up by 2 is a mystery.